# How to change the post count in wp_query for mobile?

Tags: wordpress

I have 4 posts displayed in a page. But I wanted to change it to display 1 post per page in mobile on wordpress. How do I edit it?

```
@php
  $caroselposts_carousel_width = get_sub_field('caroselposts_carousel_width');
  $i = 0;

  // Assuming CPT of post, modify accordingly
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cposts',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $caroselpost_query = new WP_Query( $args );
@endphp

@if ( $display_sidebar == 'show' )

  @php $caroselposts_carousel_width = false; @endphp

@endif

@if ( $caroselpost_query->have_posts() )

  @php
    $caroselpost_count = $caroselpost_query->post_count; 
  @endphp

  <section 
    id="component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    class="component-block component-block--caroselposts component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    data-block-type="caroselposts" 
    data-id="component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    draggable="false"
    >

    <div class="{{ $caroselposts_carousel_width == 'full_width' ? 'container-fluid' : ( $caroselposts_carousel_width == 'container' ? 'container' : '' ) }}">

      <h3 class="text-uppercase text-center mb-3">Heading</h3>

      <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel py-4" data-ride="false" data-interval="0">

        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="carousel-item {{ $i == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">

            <div class="row align-items-stretch">

              @while ( $caroselpost_query->have_posts() )

                @php
                  $caroselpost_query->the_post();
                @endphp

                @include( 'partials/section.subcomponent_single_caroselpost' )

                @php $i++; @endphp

                @if ( $i % 4 == 0 && $i != $caroselpost_count )

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">

                    <div class="row align-items-stretch">

                @endif

              @endwhile

            @php wp_reset_postdata(); @endphp

          </div>

        </div>

        @if ( $caroselpost_count > 4 )

          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselPost" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left text-dark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselPost" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right text-dark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

        @endif

      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

@endif
```

I know that I can edit to display 1 post like this in mobile

```
@if ( $i % 1 == 0 && $i != $caroselpost_count )
```

but how do I get to display in mobile version?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [wp_is_mobile](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_mobile/) to check if the current browser runs on a mobile device. and based on that you can pass `posts_per_page`. check below code.

```
@php
  $caroselposts_carousel_width = get_sub_field('caroselposts_carousel_width');
  $i = 0;

  // Assuming CPT of post, modify accordingly
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'cposts',
    'posts_per_page' => 4 ,
    'orderby' => 'menu_order',
    'order' => 'ASC'
  );
  $caroselpost_query = new WP_Query( $args );
@endphp

@if ( $display_sidebar == 'show' )

  @php $caroselposts_carousel_width = false; @endphp

@endif

@if ( $caroselpost_query->have_posts() )

  @php
    $caroselpost_count = ( wp_is_mobile() ) ? 1 : 4; 
  @endphp

  <section 
    id="component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    class="component-block component-block--caroselposts component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    data-block-type="caroselposts" 
    data-id="component-block--caroselposts-{{ get_row_index() }}" 
    draggable="false"
    >

    <div class="{{ $caroselposts_carousel_width == 'full_width' ? 'container-fluid' : ( $caroselposts_carousel_width == 'container' ? 'container' : '' ) }}">

      <h3 class="text-uppercase text-center mb-3">Heading</h3>

      <div id="carousel" class="carousel slide carousel py-4" data-ride="false" data-interval="0">

        <div class="carousel-inner">

          <div class="carousel-item {{ $i == 0 ? 'active' : '' }}">

            <div class="row align-items-stretch">

              @while ( $caroselpost_query->have_posts() )

                @php
                  $caroselpost_query->the_post();
                @endphp

                @include( 'partials/section.subcomponent_single_caroselpost' )

                @php $i++; @endphp

                @if ( $i % 4 == 0 && $i != $caroselpost_count )

                    </div>

                  </div>

                  <div class="carousel-item">

                    <div class="row align-items-stretch">

                @endif

              @endwhile

            @php wp_reset_postdata(); @endphp

          </div>

        </div>

        @if ( $caroselpost_count > 4 )

          <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselPost" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-left text-dark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
          </a>
          <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselPost" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <i class="fas fa-chevron-right text-dark" aria-hidden="true"></i>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
          </a>

        @endif

      </div>

    </div>

  </section>

@endif
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried. but it's not working. The images are still not displaying 1 per page on mobile and 4 per page on desktop....

Comment: You said  `1 post per page` not images.

Comment: Yes, the images are the posts. but the conditions depends on the post_count to display the posts in the project I was working on. I just took over the project and someone wrote it like this.

Comment: @KristinaBressler be careful when using `wp_is_mobile`. It's really not the best way to handle this, since tablets are considered mobile devices. It's not a way to check screen width, but rather device type.